# Stacking cells in a table by pairs in responsive layout

Tags: html, css, responsive

A lot of examples show how to stack cells one on one in a responsive design (it's enough to just apply display:block to all cells). What if I want the cells to stack by pairs? Let's say I have a row with 4 cells:

A B C D

And in responsive design I want something like this:

A B

C D

How could I approach this?

Comment: You have to use Media queries or use framework like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: @bklups I know I have to use media queries, I just wonder what styles do I have to apply to an existing table to make it look like I've described.

Comment: Put A B on same div (the same for C D) with width:100% or 50% according to media queries

Comment: @bklups What if it's a table (<table>)?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to support old browsers (like IE9), use `flex-basis`.

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
tr {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}

td {
  /* makes every cell at least 34% of the total width, thus
     preventing more than two cells from getting on the same row */
  flex-basis: 34%;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0thg1j7h/.

See browser support for flex at http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox.

If you DO need to support older browsers, try this solution:

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
/* all cells on one line */
/*tr {
  float: left;
}*/

/* two cells per row */
/* do nothing */

/* one cell per row */
/*td {
  display: block;
}*/
```

Here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3183v90w/1/

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I have to support IE9.

Comment: @InfinitePii is it acceptable to change your HTML so that every row contains two cells (so every tr contains two td's)? If so, I can update my answer to include a solution that should work even on very old browsers.

Comment: Yes, it is, I'd appreciate it. However the principle stays the same, so at some points (higher screen width) all the cells are displayed next to each others and at some they break like I described in my post. If you could show me how to achieve that with two trs (hopefully without dynamic DOM manipulation) that'd be awesome.

Comment: @InfinitePii I updated my answer, see if it works for you.